# Multiplication of two irrational to give rational

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

I know that we can obtain any rational $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ by the multiplication of two irrational numbers. There are many beautiful answers to this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085151/irrationals-forming-rationals).

But I want to know that if there exists a theorem/result which can exactly point out that when does (a shot of classification that) the multiplication of **given** two irrational numbers is a rational number?

If the above thing is much more to ask for, then so can we expect that we have a finite list of the product of two irrational numbers that are unsettled and others flow some general pattern or we have some theorems?

Comment: Why would the product of *any* two irrational numbers give a rational number??  $\sqrt{7} \cdot \sqrt{11}$, for example, or $\sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3}$.  In short:  some pairs do, some pairs don't.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I know that any two irrational won't give a rational number. I am asking do we have some short of classification to get a rational from given two irrationals?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Possible_transcendental_numbers and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28243/is-there-a-proof-that-pi-times-e-is-irrational may interest you.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think I have made it more concise. Check if it's clear? and can you answer it?

Comment: It's indicated that there are many unsettled products of two irrational numbers, to answer one of your question. :)

Comment: @Learning I see. But is that list finite?

Comment: What *sort* of theorem.  Sometimes two irrationals multiplied together is rational-- such as $\sqrt{\frac {32}7}$ and $\sqrt{ 14}$ (which multiplied together is $4$)... or $\frac \pi {19}$ and $\frac 7{\pi}$ (which multiplied together is $\frac 7{19}$.--- and sometimes they don't-- such as $\sqrt 7$ and $\sqrt 3$ or $\pi$ and $\sqrt 2$.  So what would you expect theorem to say?

Comment: My guess is that the list is infinite.

Comment: I really don't think there can be anything more that if $x$ and $y$ are irrational then $xy$ will be rational if if $x = r\frac 1y$ for some rational $r$.  But that's of course a *very* stupid theorem.  But I really don't think we can do any better.

Comment: @fleablood I am expecting that the theorem should give me a give check method for a pair of irrational number that when they are multiplied will give me a rational number. I think you got some bits of the question that I am asking.:) I have already mentioned that my question might not be concise. :D

Comment: But what possible *language* and description would *help* you.  The only way we have to describe a rational number is that it is a ratio of two integers and we have *no* way of describing an irrational number unless it has some "magic" geometric or a algebraic property.  So how on earth would we be able to *describe* what sort of irrational number multiple to a rational number.  It really seems we'd have to get circular and have something like the product of two irrational numbers is rational if and only if one is a rational multiple of the inverse of the other.

Comment: Try it.... say something *false*... The product of $x$ and $y$ is rational if ... what ... about $x$ and $y$.  Don't worry about saying something *true*.  Just try to say something that's coherent.

Comment: @fleablood The method of contradiction might not be powerful, otherwise we should have been able to settle the question of $\pi\times e$ as in the links by Learning.

Comment: What? I wasn't asking you to prove anything by contradiction (prove *what* by contradiction).  I was asking you to *describe* and come up with language that can possibly *describe* what such a theory might state.  "Theorem: If $x$ and $y$ are irrational then $xy$ is rational if *purple monkey dishwasher*".  What possible *words* about irrational numbers could we have that *purple monkey dishwasher* would even make sense? What *aspects* of irrational numbers *are* there that we can even use? We can describe what they *don't* do, but not what they do.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> I want to know that if there exists a theorem/result which can exactly
> point out that when does (a shot of classification that) the
> multiplication of given two irrational numbers is a rational number?

Ummm... just multiply them and find out.  Works most of the time!

Comment: Does it? `:~(  If it works, can you please tell me is $\pi\times e$ rational?

Comment: @Kumar  :Touché. Although, for ostensibly non-known products of two presumably transcendental (not merely irrational, i.e. non-algebraic) numbers such as pi times e, the likliehood of the result being irrational (or even again transcendental, I would wager) is infinitely more likely than it being rational. I believe there are infinitely more irrationals than rationals, and indeed higher-magnitude infinity more transcendentals than algebraics.   As for products of algebraic irrational numbers, I'm not sure of an algorithm or the like (of rationality of the result); I too am curious about this.